# how to insert negative value to bytearray in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I want to put negative value to `bytearray()`, So we can do it by converting it into 2`s complement but python3 supports UTF-8 encoding. When we insert 2`s complement into `bytearray()` then the encoding will be failed as

> UnicodeDecodeError: "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 0: invalid continuation byte", because of it support range up to 127.

Can anyone help me with it? Either we can put negative value to `bytearray()` or we have different encoding type to encode or decode range between 0-255.

Comment: The `bytearray` type accepts integers in the range 0..255, as is mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray), for example. The data stored in a `bytearray` don't have to be UTF-8 sequences though – it can be any data. I'm not sure how the UnicodeDecodeError and your attempt to insert negative integers are connected, however; maybe you should show some code.

Comment: Hi @lenz , So this is the problem statement: a = bytearray([236,25,60]).decode("utf-8")

Comment: This byte sequence is not valid UTF-8. What kind of data is this? If it is text, how was it encoded? If it isn't text, why do you want to decode it with UTF-8? It most probably won't work. And it makes no sense to decode non-text data into a `str`.